# Why does transferring files to a USB stick grind my computer to a halt?

Tags: windows-10, usb, performance, io

I'm currently syncing a bunch of files to a USB stick.

Regardless of what USB version it uses, and regardless of my motherboard's ability to transfer USB data, why does it cause my entire computer to crawl on its knees?

I'm not talking about the USB mouse and keyboard. I'm talking about opening image files on my SSD system disk, for example. Or rendering webpages in my browser. How can that kind of thing be affected by a heavy USB data transfer from my very fast system disk to a (possibly slow, but not really) USB stick?

It's as if my entire machine is temporarily brought down as long as the file copying (robocopy in this case) goes on. I don't understand how it's logically possible.

Looking at what the command is doing, it's currently loading various 35 MB large image files over, taking a number of seconds each. Alright, so maybe the USB memstick *is* relatively slow, but so what? Why does that effect the rest of my system? I've always been confused about how USB seems to be some sort of voodoo technology which sometimes doesn't work at all and sometimes does work and sometimes brings down the machine to its knees and sometimes does not. Whenever USB is involved, especially when transferring files or using the data bus "heavily" (presumably), it seems to cause all kinds of issues to Windows.

Why is this? What technical explanation can you offer?

Comment: Specifications of your PC would help.

Comment: @Moab It actually wouldn't. The whole point is that this has happened on so many different computers and Windows installations (and versions) over so many years, with so many different USB storage devices of all kinds and speeds.

Comment: I have only encountered such a problem when the USB was malfunctioning and Windows was heavily engaged in trying to recover from the error. Otherwise, a USB has never frozen any computer that I have worked on.

Comment: On Linux systems, the I/O Scheduler used by the kernel can impact large file transfers - https://wiki.debian.org/SSDOptimization#Low-Latency_IO-Scheduler - "The dumb "noop" scheduler may be a little faster in benchmarks that max out the throughput, but this scheduler causes noticeable delays for other tasks while large file transfers are in progress.". Maybe look for something similar in Windoze.

Comment: What is the CPU usage during the copy? Is robocopy retrying multiple times? Is the transfer speed consistent? Could you give an example of the specs of a computer that can't handle copying photos?